# iframe is not loading google map

Tags: wordpress

I am using google map in a popup coming through Fancy box where I had used type

```
 <script>
  jQuery("#menu-item-1670 a").fancybox({
                'width'             : '75%',
                'height'            : '75%',
                'autoScale'         : true,
                       'zoomSpeedIn': 300,
                      'zoomSpeedOut': 300,
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0,
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
</script>
```

but when I click on the google map then first time it shows map but when I try to click second time then it won't show up..don't know why?
here is the link I have tried to implement
http://kelts.wpengine.com/
property details tab->click on property map.->firsttime it shows->not second time.

tried but no luck!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I knew it when I click on the link again then it doesn't come with source of map..How can I fix this .Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time I open the box, the `src` attribute of the `iframe` is `about:blank`.  There's a thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/1zIbmk31sgs) that might fix the problem - it suggests storing the `src` using the `onComplete` callback, and restoring it with the `onClosed` callback.

Not sure if it applies to your particular case, but it seems worth a try.

If I've read that link and your source correctly, this should do the trick:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
      var mySRC ="";
      jQuery("#menu-item-1670 a").fancybox({
         'width'             : '75%',
         'height'            : '75%',
         'autoScale'         : true,
         'zoomSpeedIn'       : 300,
         'zoomSpeedOut'      : 300,
         'overlayOpacity'    : 0,
         'type'              : 'iframe',
         'onComplete': function() {
            // alert('onComplete called');
            mySRC = jQuery('#map_title iframe').attr('src'); 
         },
         'onClosed': function() { 
            // alert('onClosed called');
            jQuery('#map_title iframe').attr('src',mySRC); 
         } 
      });
   }); // ready 
</script>
```

If it works, dig out an answer by [JFK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk) and give him/her an upvote - it looks like he/she's the source of the code.

Comment: Unfortuantely no luck!Any other idea please!!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you weren't using `$` for jQuery.  I've updated the code.  Can you try again?

Comment: Hey Hobo! I have already tried with this as you had sent me $ code but I converted it on the Jquery syntax but no luck man!Here you can check what code I had used.Please look at the source of code you will find it on home page-footer section http://kelts.wpengine.com/ .Please help me..

Comment: I'm really not sure; I haven't hit this particular problem, and without being able to change the source myself it's a little hard to debug.  It seems the onComplete function isn't being called.  One difference I can see between JFK's code and yours is that you're not calling your code in the document ready function.  I've updated the code.  If you're not comfortable debugging, uncomment the alerts to see if the callbacks are being invoked.

Comment: Damn.  It might help if you had the right selector.  "#menu-item-1670 a" isn't the google map link.  It's the "contact lucy" link.  Try adding a selector that targets the right link.

Comment: oops !! yes that was my mistake but unfortunately its still not working can you please look on that...when I used your modified code it doesn't show up map on Fancybox

Comment: Great news.  The best way to say thanks around here is to accept the answer (click the tick beside it) and/or upvote it (click the up arrow)...